# Verify if nginx is working correctly with Proxy Protocol locally

Tags: nginx, proxy-protocol

**Environment**

I have set up Proxy Protocol support on an AWS classic load balancer as shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html) which redirects traffic to backend [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/) (configured with [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/)) instances.

Everything works great and I can hit my websites from the open internet.

Now, since my nginx configuration is done in AWS [User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), I want to do some checks before the instance starts serving traffic which is achievable through AWS Lifecycle hooks.

**Problem**

Before enabling *proxy protocol* I used to check whether my nginx instance is healthy, and ModSecurity is working by checking a `403` response from this command

```
$ curl -ks "https://localhost/foo?username=1'%20or%20'1'%20=%20'"
```

After enabling Proxy Protocol, I can't do this anymore as the command fails with below error which is expected as per this [link](https://blog.mythic-beasts.com/2016/05/09/proxy-protocol-nginx-broken-header/).

```
# curl -k https://localhost -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 443 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Encountered end of file

# cat /var/logs/nginx/error.log
2017/10/26 07:53:08 [error] 45#45: *5348 broken header: "���4"�U�8ۭ�u��%d�z��mRN�[e��<�,�
�+̩�    �0��/̨��98k�̪32g�5=�/<
" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 172.17.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

What other options do I have to programmatically check nginx apart from curl? Maybe something in some other language?

Comment: Add another listen port without proxy_protocol and have curl check that port < OR > remove proxy_protocol for localhost < OR > use a client that supports proxy_protocol.

Comment: @TanHongTat I can't use another port for security reasons. I am trying to look for some client which supports proxy protocol and ssl

Comment: Possible to call on http instead of https? Then I have a possible solution

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeah, I know it will work with http but our security team doesn't wants to open other ports any extra ports. That is my last resort ; if I do not find anything else I will probably open some random port and make it available only for the IP of this host.

Comment: You could also `listen <public IP address>:443 proxy_protocol ssl;` + `listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tarun for the detailed explanation. I discussed within the team and ended up doing creating another nginx virtual host on port 80 and using that to check ModSecurity as below.

```
curl "http://localhost/foo?username=1'%20or%20'1'%20=%20'"`
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `--haproxy-protocol` curl option, which adds the extra proxy protocol info to the request.

```
curl --haproxy-protocol localhost
```

So:

```
curl -ks "https://localhost/foo?username=1'%20or%20'1'%20=%20'"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, adding `--haproxy-protocol` is the best answer.

Comment: This is available on curl >= 7.60.0 (which was released on 16 May 2018)

Answer (score 7):

Proxy Protocol append a plain text line before the streaming anything

```
PROXY TCP4 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 0 8080
```

Above is an example, but this happens the very first thing. Now if I have a NGINX listening on SSL and http both using `proxy_protocol` then it expects to see this line first and then any other thing

So if do

```
$ curl localhost:81
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

And in nginx logs

```
web_1  | 2017/10/27 06:35:15 [error] 5#5: *2 broken header: "GET / HTTP/1.1
```

If I do

```
$ printf "PROXY TCP4 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 0 80\r\nGET /test/abc\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 81
You can reach API /test/abc and args_given = ,
```

It works. As I am able to send the proxy protocol it accepts

Now in case of SSL if I use below

```
printf "PROXY TCP4 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 0 8080\r\nGET /test/abc\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect localhost:8080
```

It would still error out

```
web_1  | 2017/10/27 06:37:27 [error] 5#5: *1 broken header: ",(��   @_5���_'���/��ߗ
```

That is because the client is trying to do Handshake first instead of sending proxy protocol first then handshake

So you possible solutions are

1. Terminate SSL on LB and then handle http on nginx with proxy_protocol and use the the nc command option I posted
2. Add a `listen 127.0.0.1:<randomlargeport>` and execute your test using the same. This is still safe as you are listening to localhost only
3. Add another SSL port and use `listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl` and `listen <private_ipv4>:443 ssl proxy_protocol`

All solutions are in priority order as per my choice, you can make your own choice

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately bash version didn't work in my case, so I wrote python3 code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import sys

def check_status(host, port):
    '''Check app status, return True if ok'''
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.settimeout(3)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall(b'GET /status HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.example.com\r\nUser-Agent: curl7.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data.decode().endswith('OK'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
try:
    status = check_status('127.0.0.1', 80)
except:
    status = False
if status:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit(1)
```